# How to split Chinese characters in PHP?

Tags: php, split, character, cjk

I need some help regarding how to split Chinese characters mixed with English words and numbers in PHP.

For example, if I read

```
FrontPage 2000中文版應用大全
```

I'm hoping to get

```
FrontPage, 2000, 中,文,版,應,用,大,全
```

or

```
FrontPage, 2,0,0,0, 中,文,版,應,用,大,全
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This answer does what the accepted answer's first snippet does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55783469/2943403

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you are using UTF-8 (or you can convert it to UTF-8 using Iconv or some other tools), then using the `u` modifier (doc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php )

```php
<?
    $s = "FrontPage 2000中文版應用大全";
    print_r(preg_match_all('/./u', $s, $matches));
    echo "\n";
    print_r($matches);
?>
```

will give

```
21
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => F
            [1] => r
            [2] => o
            [3] => n
            [4] => t
            [5] => P
            [6] => a
            [7] => g
            [8] => e
            [9] =>  
            [10] => 2
            [11] => 0
            [12] => 0
            [13] => 0
            [14] => 中
            [15] => 文
            [16] => 版
            [17] => 應
            [18] => 用
            [19] => 大
            [20] => 全
        )

)
```

Note that my source code is stored in a file encoded in UTF-8 also, for the $s to contain those characters.

The following will match alphanumeric as a group:

```
<?
$s = "FrontPage 2000中文版應用大全";
print_r(preg_match_all('/(\w+)|(.)/u', $s, $matches));
echo "\n";
print_r($matches[0]);
?>
```

result:

```
10
Array
(
    [0] => FrontPage
    [1] =>  
    [2] => 2000
    [3] => 中
    [4] => 文
    [5] => 版
    [6] => 應
    [7] => 用
    [8] => 大
    [9] => 全
)
```

Comment: Note that using just `.` does not match character compositions like `ä` (composition of U+0061 and U+0308).

Comment: @動靜能量Sorry, I can't vote up, not enough reputation; honestly I would if I could.

Answer (score 3):

```php
    /**
     * Reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html
     * Korean: Hangul
     * CJK: Han
     * Japanese: Hiragana, Katakana
     * Flag u required
     */

    preg_match_all(
        '/\p{Hangul}|\p{Hiragana}|\p{Han}|\p{Katakana}|(\p{Latin}+)|(\p{Cyrillic}+)/u',
        $str,
        $result
    );
```

This one is working if you are using PHP 7.0 too.

This one is just not working. I regret I have upvoted a non-working solution....

```php
<?
    $s = "FrontPage 2000中文版應用大全";
    print_r(preg_match_all('/(\w+)|(.)/u', $s, $matches));
    echo "\n";
    print_r($matches[0]);
?>
```

Comment: but your solution doesn't include Punctuation Marks. Punctuation Marks does matter in chinese!

Comment: @fmchan You can find coresponding Unicode and use Unicode range in RegEx. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458654/regular-expressions-for-a-range-of-unicode-points-php https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+3002

Answer (score 1):

With this code you can make chinese text (utf8) to wrap at the end of the line so that it is still readable

```
print_r(preg_match_all('/([\w]+)|(.)/u', $str, $matches));
$arr_result = array();

foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $val) {
    $arr_result[]=$val;
    $arr_result[]="&#8203;"; //add Zero-Width Space
} 
foreach ($arr_result as $key => $val) {
    $out .= $val;
} 
return $out;
```