# PHP: How to match a range of unicode paired surrogates emoticons/emoji?

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-replace, unicode-escapes

[*anubhava*'s answer about matching ranges of unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26458714/6225838) led me to the regex to use for cleaning up a specific range of single code point of characters. With it, now I can match all [miscellaneous symbols in this list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/miscellaneous_symbols/list.htm) (includes emoticons) with this simple expression:

```
preg_replace('/[\x{2600}-\x{26FF}]/u', '', $str);
```

However, I also want to match those in this [list of paired/double surrogates emoji](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/emoticons/list.htm), but as [nhahtdh explained in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458654/regular-expressions-for-a-range-of-unicode-points-php#comment41557386_26458714):

> There is a range from `d800` to `dfff` to specify surrogates in UTF-16 to allow for more characters to be specified. A **single surrogate is not a valid character in UTF-16 (a pair is necessary** to specify a valid character).

So, for example, when I try this:

```
preg_replace('/\x{D83D}\x{DE00}/u', '', $str);
```

For replacing only the first of the [paired surrogates on this list](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/emoticons/list.htm), i.e.:

PHP throws this:

> `preg_replace()`: Compilation failed: disallowed Unicode code point `(&gt;= 0xd800 &amp;&amp; &lt;= 0xdfff)`

I have tried several different combinations, including the supposed combination of the above code points in [UTF8 for](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f600/index.htm)  (`'/[\x{00F0}\x{009F}\x{0098}\x{0080}]/u'`), but I was still unable to match it. I also looked into other [PCRE pattern modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), but it seems `u` is the only one that allows to point through UTF8.

Am I missing any "escape" alternative here?

Comment: Are you just trying to build a regex to match those 80 emojis and use it as a "hardcoded" pattern, or are you trying to write code that will "transpile" `U+1F600` into `\x{D83D}\x{DE00}`?

Comment: Which PHP version?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew both if possible. The _hardcoded_ pattern would be a range.

Comment: @revo PHP 7.1.5 and above.

Comment: If your PHP isn't shipped with a PCRE build for UTF-16 then you can't perform such a match. From PHP 7.0 on, you're able to use Unicode code points following this syntax `\u{XXXX}` e.g. `preg_replace("~\u{1F600}~", '', $str);` (Mind the double quotes)

Comment: @revo wow, completely forgot about this (I read the _new_ features a while ago)... Thank you for this, I came up with this [solution for concatenating both types of ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51951236/6225838).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[revo's comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947319/php-how-to-match-a-range-of-unicode-paired-surrogates-emoticons-emoji?noredirect=1#comment90849424_51947319) was very helpful to find a solution:

> If your PHP isn't shipped with a PCRE build for UTF-16 then you can't perform such a match. **From PHP 7.0 on**, you're able to use Unicode code points following this syntax `\u{XXXX}` e.g. `preg_replace("~\u{1F600}~", '', $str);` (Mind the **double quotes**)

Since I am using PHP 7, `echo "\u{1F602}";` outputs  according to this [PHP RFC page on **unicode escape**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/unicode_escape). This proposal was in essence:

> A new escape sequence is added for **double-quoted strings** and heredocs.
>
> - `\u{  codepoint-digits  }` where `codepoint-digits` is composed of hexadecimal digits.

This implies that the matching string in `preg_replace` (normally single-quoted for not messing up with double-quoted strings variable expansion), now needs some [`preg_quote` *magic*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php#80049). This is the solution I came up with:

```
preg_replace(
  // single point unicode list
  "/[\x{2600}-\x{26FF}".
  // http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/miscellaneous_symbols/list.htm
  // concatenates with paired surrogates
  preg_quote("\u{1F600}", '/')."-".preg_quote("\u{1F64F}", '/').
  // https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/emoticons/list.htm
  "]/u",
  '',
  $str
);
```

Here's the [proof of the above in 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/J76IH).

## EDIT: a simpler solution

In [another comment made by revo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947319/php-how-to-match-a-range-of-unicode-paired-surrogates-emoticons-emoji/51951236#comment90853125_51951236), it seems that by placing unicode characters directly into the regex character class, single-quoted strings and previous PHP versions (e.g. 4.3.4) are supported:

```
preg_replace('/[☀-⛿-]/u','YOINK',$str);
```

For using [PHP 7's *new* feature though](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/unicode_escape), you still need double-quotes:

```
preg_replace("/[\u{2600}-\u{26FF}\u{1F600}-\u{1F64F}]/u",'YOINK',$str);
```

Here's [revo's proof in 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/uA3mD).

Comment: I'd like to add you neither need `preg_quote`  nor PCRE's `\x{XXXX}` syntax. Just go with `/[\u{2600}-\u{26FF}\u{1F600}-\u{1F64F}]/u`. This is equal to `/[☀-⛿-]/u`. See live demo here https://3v4l.org/uA3mD

Comment: @revo haha, this is amazing! Directly placing the characters allow replacements in PHP 4! I guess this is the best solution (if the IDE doesn't freak out). I edited the answer with your discovery. Thank you very much!