# regular expression to match characters that are not Unicode letter characters

Tags: php, regex

I am writing an app in Spanish, and I know that I can match Unicode letter characters with `\p{L}` which will include letters with accents like é and ñ. However, how would I match characters that are NOT Unicode letter characters?

Using `[^\p{L}]` still seems to match letter-characters.

For example, in php, I am doing the following:

```
$pattern = '/[\p{L}]+/';
$subject = 'é';
echo preg_match($pattern, $subject); // echoes 1 as expected
```

which works as expected. However,

```
$pattern = '/[^\p{L}]+/';
$subject = 'é';
echo preg_match($pattern, $subject); // still echoes 1?
```

I was expecting the result to be 0 since `é` should not be included in `[^\p{L}]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expressions for a range of unicode points PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458654/regular-expressions-for-a-range-of-unicode-points-php).

Comment: The "possible duplicate" makes no mention of Unicode letter characters, especially Spanish characters like é or ñ.

Comment: @LeoGalleguillos, every letter in your question and your comment (and Tim's, and mine) is a Unicode character. That's the whole point of Unicode—it's designed to cover every character that exists today or will exist tomorrow. ASCII is a subset of Unicode. Latin, Cyrillic, Kanji, emoji… it's all Unicode. You need to figure out the range(s) you care about.

Comment: Right, but I am trying to write a regex that matches all characters that are NOT Unicode letter characters.