# regex POSIX expression for half space,semi space or zero space

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, smarty

There is a POSIX bracket expression list like `[:alnum:]`, `[:alpha:]`...

https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

which one is for half space or semi space or zero space?

**EDIT1**: actually, i am using PHP `regex_replace` in smarty code, like below

```
{$title|regex_replace:'/[^[:punct:][:alnum:][:space:]]/u':''}
```

This code,replace all characters with null,except than puctuation,alpha numeric and space.

But unfortunately, it also replaces half space with null string.

For example: unicode persian string $title = '☺این‌یک تست (آزمایش) است‌'

will change to 'اینیک تست (آزمایش) است‌'.

But the correct string should be 'این‌یک تست (آزمایش) است‌'

As you see, it also replace half space in 'این‌یک' with null value and convert it to 'اینیک'

I want to prevent it.

**EDIT2**: half space or zero space is :

Decimal character code: `8204`

Hexadecimal character code: `0x200c`

HTML character reference: `&zwnj;`

Java string: `\u200c`

**A SOLUTION**:
If i add persian(farsi) keyboard to windows and change keyboard language to persian(farsi), then

if i use SHIFT+SPACE to add a half space between two latest brackets ]] , it works great! :

```
{$title|regex_replace:'/[^[:punct:][:alnum:][:space:]‌]/u':''}
```

(There is a half space character between latest two brackets using persian keyboard)

But unfortunately it does not work using hex code `\x200c`, and i don't know why!?

Comment: Add `\x{200C}` to the character class: `[^[:punct:][:alnum:][:space:]\x{200C}]`

Comment: @revo, Thanks, but it does not work neither with `regex_replace` nor PHP `preg_replace`

Comment: What does it mean exactly when you say *it does not work*? Does it throw an error?

Comment: @revo, Yes it throws error. correct syntax is `[^[:punct:][:alnum:][:space:][\x200C]]`, but the result is '☺این‌یک تست (آزمایش) است‌'. It is a progress, but still need to remove symbol characters like ☺

Comment: That's not the correct usage. Please show us the error.

Comment: @revo, it's a smarty syntax error:`Smarty error: syntax error: unrecognized tag: $title|regex_replace:'/[^[:punct:][:alnum:][:space:]\x{200C`

Comment: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.escaping.tpl   you need to escape your {}, 1)    {literal}[^[:punct:][:alnum:][:space:]\x{200C}]{/literal}      2) [^[:punct:][:alnum:][:space:]\x{ldelim}200C{rdelim}]

Comment: @Simon, both of them throw syntax error.

Comment: have you tried experimenting with https://regex101.com/ ?

Comment: @nuiun, Yes. but unfortunately it doesn't accept `/u` parameter which is important for unicode characters

Answer (score 1):

The standard POSIX character classes generally capture *classes* of characters. If you want to match the character [U+2002](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2002/index.htm) then simply match exactly that character, literally or using whatever symbolic representation your programming language supports.

Python:

```
r = re.compile('\u2002')
if r.match(somestring):
    ...
```

Though of course, you don't need a regex for that:

```
if '\u2002' in somestring:
    ...
```

(I'm guessing you mean U+2002; there's a [number of other spaces](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html), none of which has a name which exactly contains "half space". A modern POSIX `[:space:]` should match all of them, of course.)

**Update:** If PHP's `[:space:]` is not properly POSIX and/or Unicode-compliant, probably simply add the code point to your expression.

```
{$title|regex_replace:'/[^[:punct:][:alnum:][:space:]\x{2002}]/u':''}
```

(with kudos to [Regular expressions for a range of unicode points PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458654/regular-expressions-for-a-range-of-unicode-points-php))

Comment: Obviously `[:space:]` then, as already covered in this answer. But I have no faith that PHP in particular implements this correctly.

Comment: No, it seems half space is not included in `[:space:]`

Comment: PHP still has no Unicode support at all, does it? So you will need to enumerate the precise UTF-8 strings you want to match (assuming your data's encoding is UTF-8 obviously).

Comment: Yes you right, but this syntax `{$title|regex_replace:'/[^[:punct:][:alnum:][:space:]\x{2002}]/u':''}` does not work in smarty.

Answer (score -1):

You could replace *any* separators (`\p{Z}`) with a standard full space *before* applying the actual regular expression. Here doing both sequentially :

```
preg_replace(['/(\p{Z})/', '[^[:punct:][:alnum:][:space:]]/u'], [' ', ''], $title)
```

Comment: I don't want to replace half or zero space with standard space. i want to show it as it is.